# python pandas how to combine slices after using for

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe, with two columns and 5000 rows.
like:
   A   B
0  1   4
1  5   5
2  3   2
3  9   7
...
5000  8  3

I want to separate the dataframe every 100 steps. So I get 50 slices.
For a training, what's I want to do next is to combine the 50 slices again into a new dataframe or array or everything that I can output the data into csv file.

I used the command following to separate the dataframe into slices:

```
df_original=pd.read_csv('/data.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(df_original, columns=['A','B'])
for i in range(0,len(df['A']),100):
    df_100=df[i:i+100]
```

After doing the command above, how can I combine the slices for next step?
Any advice would be helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Use df.append()

Comment: Are you sure your code above will give you 50 dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I think I got 50 slices after running the code above.

Comment: But you only have df_100 to store the sliced dataframe. You should only get the last slice by that code..

Comment: Right, when I used .to_csv, I only got the last slice. But since it is a for loop, I do got 50 results, but df_100 will only equals to the last result. That is want I want to solve, to get every result and save as csv file.

Comment: I wrote anwer, hope that helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want have 50 csv files:

```
for i in range(0,len(df['A']),100):
    df_100=df[i:i+100]
    df_100.to_csv("file"+str(i)+".csv", index=False)
```

If you want to do some process to those sliced dataframes, you can store them in as dictionary:

```
dict_of_df = {}
for i in range(0,len(df['A']),100):
    dict_of_df["slice{}".format(i)]=df[i:i+100]
```

So you will access to sliced dataframe by `dict_of_df[key]`, where `key = "slice0", "slice100", "slice200", ...`

When you have done with those sliced dataframes and want to combine them,

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for key, values in dict_of_df.items():
    df_final = df_final.append(dict_of_df[key])
```

Check if df_final isn't sorted well, then:

```
df_final = df_final.sort_index()
```

And export back to csv: `df_final.to_csv("filename.csv")`

Comment: Dear bakka, thank you so much, this is what I want! Thanks a lot!